# Product Data Transfer in Store Magento2.3.2

Tags: multistore, magento2.3.2

**Currently in My Site I have 2 Store**

1. Store 1
2. Store 2

I Want copy Data "**Store 2**" to "**Store 1**"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can enable 2nd store also in the product rather than transferring all to that store again.

Comment: not understanding please explain briefly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In
>   `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Save.php`
>   File You Can See **copyToStores** Function.
>
> After Review This Function I Got The Solution.

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$params = $_SERVER;
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('global');

$productFactory = $obj->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory');

$productCollection = $productFactory->create()->getCollection()
    ->getAllIds();
try {
    foreach ($productCollection as $productId) {
        $obj->create(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::class)
            ->setStoreId(1)
            ->load($productId)
            ->setStoreId(0)
            ->setCopyFromView(true)
            ->save();
        echo "Product Id :- " . $productId, PHP_EOL;
    }
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo "Error :- " . $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
}
```